# Update twitter status using C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
try
{
    Twitter t = new Twitter(username.Text, password.Password);

    t.Status.Update(textbox.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
}
```

This is my code using `twitterizer.framework.dll`, resulting in an exception:

```
"The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized."
```

Comment: What is your question?
What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know about your library, but Unauthorized generally means that authentication failed in some way, so wrong username/password, or maybe there's some sort of process you need to go through before you can interact with Twitter programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Which API are you using?

Twitter’s API 1.0 has been retired and version 1.1 of the API has been introduced. The new API requires that all requests be authorized (via `oAuth`) and served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

the give function works for me:

```
  public static void Tweet(string tweet)
{
    var consumerKey = "me";
    var consumerSecret = "me";
    string accessToken = "me-me";
    string AccessTokenSecret = "me";

    TwitterService service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
       //service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, AccessTokenSecret);

    SendTweetOptions options = new SendTweetOptions();
    options.Status = tweet;

    service.SendTweet(options);
}
```

Comment: get string tweet from botton click as Tweet(TextBox1.Text);